# Xcode - Cannot disable indexing

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

I have been fighting this for a about a week now. I CANNOT get indexing to disable in Xcode. Has anyone else ever experienced this? The following command has zero effect:

defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1

I relaunch Xcode after issuing this via terminal (as root) and when I re-open xcode, projects attempt to index. I have repaired permissions on the machine and upgraded to the latest xcode to no avail. Its driving me crazy as I am taking a huge hit in performance due to indexing on a very large project. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just leave the indexing finish. Disabling Indexing has no benefit on performance, except you might skip waiting

Comment: The problem is, due to the size of the project, indexing pegs my cpu to 100% and doesnt seem to progress. Even after 30 minutes of indexing.

Comment: Just leave it overnight :)

Comment: I actually figured it out finally. The IDEIndexDisable boolean was missing from com.apple.dt.XCode completely. Naturally the value couldnt be set from the command line with the value missing. I added the value manually by editing the plist file and adding the IDEIndexDisable boolean and setting it to yes. Finally, no more indexing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually figured it out finally. The `IDEIndexDisable` boolean was missing from `com.apple.dt.XCode` completely. Naturally the value couldn't be set from the command line with the value missing. I added the value manually by editing the plist file and adding the `IDEIndexDisable` boolean and setting it to `yes`. Finally, no more indexing!

EDIT: In order to edit the plist file --

Open the plist file in Xcode - its located at ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist

Find the IDEIndexDisable boolean and change it to yes

In my case the boolean was actually missing and I had to add it.

Comment: @SteveWeaver This did it!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I used to edit the `com.apple.dt.XCode.plist` file:

1 Open the file in XCode (but don't save it)

2 Edit the file by adding a new property called `IDEIndexDisable`, with type `Boolean` and value set to `YES` (to add a new property tap on the `+` button on the first property underneath Root node)

3 Export the file under a new filename in same directory, ex. `myfile.plist` under `~/Library/Preferences/`

4 Quit XCode

5 Create a backup of the original `com.apple.dt.XCode.plist` file (in case something goes wrong you can revert to this file -- always a good practice)

6 Rename/copy the exported file to the original filename, ex. in Terminal do

`% mv myfile.plist com.apple.dt.XCode.plist`

7 Reopen XCode, you should now not have indexing